# dynamically calculate div position in

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, position

In looking to build a table seating/planning app. currently got a round table that i can dynamically add chairs around using code i found on stackoverflow. function is calculating the x,y absolut position of each seat around the table.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kvb0vre0dwtc0i/table.mov?dl=0

the video shows what i got so far.

for anyone interested the code for that is

```
export const calcRoundDimensions = (totalChairs, chairSize) => {
    var chairspos = [];

    var squareSize = chairSize * 2;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalChairs; i++) {
        var top = String(squareSize/2 + (-squareSize/2-chairSize) * Math.cos((360 / totalChairs / 180) * (i + 0) * Math.PI)) + 'px';
        var left = String(squareSize/2 + (squareSize/2+chairSize) * (true ? Math.sin((360 / totalChairs / 180) * (i + 0) * Math.PI) : -Math.sin((360 / totalChairs / 180) * (i + 0) * Math.PI))) + 'px';
        chairspos.push({top:top, left:left});
    }

    return {chairpos:chairspos, size:squareSize+chairSize};
}
```

I'm looking to do the same with a square one (also a rectangular one, but first thing's first).

square table would be fixed width (150px). I'm looking too be able to add chairs clockwise and have them centred on the side. (will have a 12 or 16 chair limit but this shouldn't matter i guess).

rectangle table would have one chair at either end then be able to add 5 or six chair on each of the longer ends.

searched the site but wasn't able to find much direction.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you should edit your question:
1. be more specific
2. work on grammer

Comment: 3. show what you have tried. this is not a code writing service

Comment: @NirpendraPatel. i've added a video. I belive, together with the question, things should be more then clear now. As for the grammar I'm sure its on a more then decent level for a non english speaker

Comment: @gforce301 i wasn't expecting ready made code. im looking for an idea/point in the right direction on how to achieve what i'm after. i wouldn't be here if i knew. translating something i already know how to do in javascript is not exactly rocket science.

Comment: "i wasn't expecting ready made code" but you didn't bother to read what was expected of you as a poster ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). "translating something i already know how to do in javascript is not exactly rocket science", Well if it's so easy to do then why on earth are you asking for help here at all?

Comment: @gforce301 i believe the question (especially after the edit) is more then clear. no code was submited as I DIDNT WRITE ANY. my comment stated i didn't think this place is a code writing service. im looking or an ideea / rough algorithm on how one would get this done. i can easily implement it after that. i do hope a mod will remove your comments as they provide 0 help and only waste server CPU cycles. thanks for your (lack of) help. kindly point your attention elsewhere.

Comment: Your question, even in it's current form (by the rules of this site), doesn't merit any help. I't unclear what you're asking (as the only answer states), you haven't really tried anything, you haven't described how you wish to accomplish your task (for instance: how do you want to distribute an odd number, say 3, chairs around a square table?) and you have yet to go to the help section and understand what you should be asking about here and how.

Comment: As i've already stated i couldn't post any code as what im after is the logic part of the problem. not the implementation. if you can't understand why i can't post any code you can just as well go back and answer questions about missing semicolons. if you'd read the docs you point to, instead of being an asshole, you'd see the question is more the on topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: the answer below was given before i've edited my question. i dont see how this can be described better. 
also the fact that the person answering didn't understand the question doesn't necesarily imply the question was/is bad worded. it just implies he didnt understand it. your logic is off.
as my question states, chairs would be added clockwise. so any normal person would understand each chair would go on a side. start, say, top, then go to the next ones (eg, right, bottom, left). i do hope atleast now you could wrap your head on how an odd numer of chair would be distributed. if not...

Answer (score 0):

Not super clear on what you need but the following will get you positions of elements compared to the absolute top and left of the page:

```
const box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
const elementPosition = {
  x:box.x+window.scrollX,
  y:box.y+window.scrollY
};
```